# Core Data where do I need to call save method

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am using core data and I am confused about `NSManagedObjectContext`. I used following code to save my book data. Book data is saving in my one of my application extension side like following. Extension side code block is calling in different than main thread like in the image.
[image]

I am wondering does it cause a problem because of misusing of my contexts?

```
func saveBook() {
    let book: Book = Book(context: viewContext)
    let uuid = UUID()
    book.sessionId = uuid
    book.appId = session.appId
    book.startedAt = session.startedAt
    book.createdBy = AppData.installId

    coreData.saveSync()
}

func saveSync() {
        let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        privateContext.parent = viewContext
        privateContext.perform {
            do {
                try privateContext.save()
                viewContext.performAndWait {
                    do  {
                        try viewContext.save()
                    } catch {
                        let nsError = error as NSError
                        print("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                print("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see two problems in your code:

1. The privateContext in the saveSync function is ponintless, as the new Book object was created in the mainContext. So, when you save the privateContext you are saving an empty context that has no changes.
2. If I understand well, your saveBook() function is being executed in a background thread, and you are using the mainContext, which is always associated with the main thread.

When dealing with Core Data in a multi-thread environment, you need to remember the following rule: **Never use an NSManagedObjectContext or an NSManagedObject in a queue/thread other than the one assigned to your context**, or you get unexpected results and your app will crash at some point.

So, to fix both issues, you can do the following:

```
func saveBook() {
    let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    privateContext.parent = viewContext
    privateContext.perform {
        let book: Book = Book(context: privateContext)
        let uuid = UUID()
        book.sessionId = uuid
        book.appId = session.appId
        book.startedAt = session.startedAt
        book.createdBy = AppData.installId
        
        do {
            try privateContext.save()
            viewContext.performAndWait {
                do  {
                    try viewContext.save()
                } catch {
                    let nsError = error as NSError
                    print("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
                }
            }
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            print("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that, when you save the privateContext, the data are not persisted to the persistent store but are "saved" to its parent context. And it will only be persisted when the mainContext is saved. That's why you need to save both contexts after the Book object is created.

If you have the persistentStoreContainer handy in your class or structure, you can use the following approach to create a background context and save it:

```
func saveBook() {
    let privateContext = persistentStoreContainer.newBackgroundContext()
    privateContext.perform {
        let book: Book = Book(context: privateContext)
        let uuid = UUID()
        book.sessionId = uuid
        book.appId = session.appId
        book.startedAt = session.startedAt
        book.createdBy = AppData.installId

        do {
            try privateContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            print("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that the data is persisted when you save the privateContext, since its parent is the persistentStoreCoordinator.

**Edit:**

Here's another approach for creating a background context from the persistent container:

```
func saveBook() {
    persistentStoreContainer.performBackgroundTask { context in
        let book: Book = Book(context: privateContext)
        let uuid = UUID()
        book.sessionId = uuid
        book.appId = session.appId
        book.startedAt = session.startedAt
        book.createdBy = AppData.installId

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            print("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for great comment it made me clear but I have still some points. For example what if I save to main context without creating a newBackgroundContext? Or do you have any core data manager class that handles these properly?

Comment: Yes, you can use the main context only, as long as the saveBook() function is executed in the main thread. So, check if this function is not being called from any asynchronous block such as callbacks or completionHandlers. If you are not sure, the safest approach is using one of the options above. I've added another way to handle that, in which the persistent container executes a block and provides a context associated with it.

Comment: When we use `performBackgroundTask` don't we need to specify parent context and save it for also?

Comment: No, because the persist store container will create the new context and assign the store coordinator as its parent.

Comment: If I use `newBackgroundContext()` shall I add `privateContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true` also?

Comment: I don’t think it’s the case in your scenario. But if between creating the newBackgroundContext and saving it, an object in the parent context changes and the changes need to be propagated to the background context, than yes, you should set that flag.

Comment: I know I already asked lots of question but there is another one in my mind. What if I call fetch on my `viewContext` do I need to wrap `perform` or `performAndWait`?

Comment: clear and good explanation